# How To Install Android 5 on an LG G Pad 7.0?

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, lg

I have an LG G Pad 7.0 running Android KitKat (4.4.2). Could I update it to Android 5, even though there is no release for the G Pad 7?

I would also by fine with the latest version of CyanogenMod.

Also, I am very new to Android, but is it flexible in the way that you can change the Android version easily, or install another UI?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android is releasing an official update to Android 5.0 for all LG G Pad devices. It will be out soon according to [this website](http://m.gadgets.ndtv.com/tablets/news/lg-g-pad-tablets-to-start-receiving-android-50-lollipop-update-this-month-674032)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is relatively easy (compared to apple). The basic steps you will have to take are as follows:

1. Unlock the bootloader, can vary massively in difficulty by device, depending on how irritating your manufacturer's being. This will wipe all your data, but theoretically is the last time you ever have to wipe your data.
2. Install a custom rom of your choice

In order to find more concise tutorials, explaining step by step, do a google search for "lg g pad 7.0 (LTE?) bootloader unlock"

Comment: So I've found that it is possible to do a bootloader unlock, but there are no ROMS for the G Pad 7. Is there an Android 5.0 ROM that was made for the G Pad 7 out there, or are we still waiting on one?

Comment: From what I have seen you are still waiting for one, you may be able to find an alpha build if you look hard enough